# Python Bot API: Set messages to read after some time

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-api

I have a bot which polls data regularly from some input and if a specific logic applies, sends a message to a telegram channel.

The messages are only relevant for readers if the reader in the channel more or less directly read the message, i.e. after let's say 30 min, the message is irrelevant. I do not want to delete the message for historic purposes, BUT I'd like to set it to read for everyone.

1. Is there a way to set the "read"-status for the receivers? Is it possible to do so, i.e. change, for already sent, i.e. previous messages?
2. To avoid having to keep track of sent messages with their timings, is it even possible to specify that directly when sending the message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The read status can only be changed by the user itself. Anything *not* mentioned in the official API docs at https://core.telegram.org/bots/api can not be done with Telegram Bots.

As a side note: AFAIK the read status is not binary for each user. This can be observed by noting that viewing a channel message from different devices/clients with the same account will up the view count by more than 1.

Comment: `viewing a channel message from different devices/clients with the same account will up the view count by more than 1.`. Thanks for the sidenote. I have always been surprised / wondering, why view count may be bigger than number of accounts in the channel. Thanks!!